# Is there a way to maintain two concentration spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, concentration

Assuming I play a high-level Wizard in D&D 5, with access to magic items and most of the published content. Is there a way for me to maintain two spells that normally both require concentration at the same time?

I need them to apply on me, as (mostly cosmetic) buffs, so the Suggestion from Guards and Wards wouldn't work.

Comment: We’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.